# Five player congestion/crowding game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I would like the community's help with a game I am trying to solve.

In this instance of a congestion game we have five commuters $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, $E$ $(n=5)$ and two allowable resources which are bus and car. These are the strategies of our players.
$c_i$  is the cost of each commuter using their own car where $i ∈ \{A, B, C, D, E\}$ and they are fixed: 
$c_A = 1$, $c_B = 3$, $c_C = 5$, $c_D = 7$, $c_E = 9$.
Commute time by bus depends on how many others take the bus and that can be seen below and the cost would be the same for each:

```
People      Cost
1            10
2             8
3             6
4             4
5             2
```

I am trying to find Nash Equilibrium here and eliminate Dominated strategies but I am struggling with it. The first thing I did was create a [matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wBW6.png) where you can see the costs where column is commuters taking the car and row is number of commuters taking the bus:

Can someone let me know if there's better way to create the matrix so I can showcase iterated elimination of dominated strategies and NE?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A$ will go by car, since their car costs are lower than the bus cost can be.

That leaves $4$ people who might go by bus, so the bus will cost at least $4$, so $B$ will go by car.

And so on.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that the NE would be everyone going by car?

Comment: Also what would the price of stability be?

Comment: @Tumblr_user: Yes, it does mean that the only Nash equilibrium is everyone going by car. The price of stability, as defined in [this lecture](https://people.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~ycheung/AGT_CE_MD/lec_02.pdf), is the ratio of the total cost in equilibrium, $1+3+5+7+9=25$, to the minimal total cost $5\cdot2=10$, which is $\frac{25}{10}=\frac52$.